# How to avoid overfull error with url package?

Tags: errors, urls

Here is sample code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

The following web sites will be useful in your study of calculus.
\begin{itemize}
\item AP\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} Calculus BC Course Description (College Board)

\url{https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-calculus-course-description.pdf}

\item AP\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} Calculus BC Exam Information and Prior Years' Free-Response Questions

\url{http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/members/exam/exam_information/8031.html}

\item AP\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} Calculus Multiple Choice Collection ({\bf Warning -- Huge File})

\url{http://crunchymath.weebly.com/uploads/8/2/4/0/8240213/ap_multiple_choice.pdf}

\item Calculus Applets

\url{http://www.personal.psu.edu/dpl14/java/calculus/index.html}

\item Mathematics Stack Exchange

\url{http://math.stackexchange.com/}

\item Wolfram Alpha

\url{http://www.wolframalpha.com/}

\item Desmos Graphing Calculator

\url{https://www.desmos.com/calculator}

\item Visual Calculus

\url{http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However it gives overfull errors.  How to fix?

Comment: BTW removal of classicthesis package does not fix problem.  I think it is something having to do with automatic indent of \itemize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `url` documentation:

> You can allow some spacing around the breakable characters by assigning
>
> `\Urlmuskip = 0mu plus 1mu`
>
> (with `mu` units because of math mode).

In your case it seems to don't suffice, so you can try with:

```
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 2mu
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 2mu

\begin{document}


The following web sites will be useful in your study of calculus.
\begin{itemize}
\item AP\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} Calculus BC Course Description (College Board)

\url{https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-calculus-course-description.pdf}

\item AP\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} Calculus BC Exam Information and Prior Years' Free-Response Questions

\url{http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/members/exam/exam_information/8031.html}

\item AP\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} Calculus Multiple Choice Collection ({\bf Warning -- Huge File})

\url{http://crunchymath.weebly.com/uploads/8/2/4/0/8240213/ap_multiple_choice.pdf}

\item Calculus Applets

\url{http://www.personal.psu.edu/dpl14/java/calculus/index.html}

\item Mathematics Stack Exchange

\url{http://math.stackexchange.com/}

\item Wolfram Alpha

\url{http://www.wolframalpha.com/}

\item Desmos Graphing Calculator

\url{https://www.desmos.com/calculator}

\item Visual Calculus

\url{http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @JohnMolokach You're welcome.

Comment: This isn't working for me when the overfull links are in the bibliography (using biblatex).