# How to fix URL overfull & underfull on emumeration?

Tags: enumerate, urls, warnings, quoting, badness

Backed by several questions' answers, I was able to remove several warnings from my enumeration quote box, except this warning:

```
test.tex:41: Underfull \hbox (badness 2913) in paragraph at lines 41--42

Underfull \hbox (badness 2913) in paragraph at lines 41--42
[]\T1/cmr/m/n/12 Google []$\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 http : / / directory . google . com 
/ Top / Computers / Programming /
```

This is how I compile it `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test.tex` with MikTex version:

```
pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX  (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)

using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.53.1; using libcurl/7.53.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.29; using 1.6.29
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.4.5; using LibreSSL 2.4.5
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with poppler version 0.53.0
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

This is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% Change background color for text block
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238294/change-background-color-for-text-block
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{219, 229, 241}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{
colback=shadecolor,
grow to right by=-2mm,
grow to left by=-2mm,
boxrule=0pt,
boxsep=0pt,
breakable
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261776/how-to-avoid-overfull-error-with-url-package
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 2mu

\begin{document}

    \begin{myquote}
    \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,leftmargin=*]

        \sloppy
        \item {\RaggedRight Free \url{http://members.magnet.at/johann.langhofer/products/jxbeauty/overview.html} (has JBuilder support) }

        \item {\RaggedRight Google \url{http://directory.google.com/Top/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Development_Tools/Code_Beautifiers/?tc=1} }

    \end{enumerate}
    \end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

This is how the PDF looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\RaggedRight` usage is wrong (so it did nothing) you want

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% Change background color for text block
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238294/change-background-color-for-text-block
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{219, 229, 241}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{
colback=shadecolor,
grow to right by=-2mm,
grow to left by=-2mm,
boxrule=0pt,
boxsep=0pt,
breakable
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261776/how-to-avoid-overfull-error-with-url-package
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 2mu

\begin{document}

    \begin{myquote}\RaggedRight
    \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,leftmargin=*]

        \sloppy
        \item  Free \url{http://members.magnet.at/johann.langhofer/products/jxbeauty/overview.html} (has JBuilder support) 

        \item Google \url{http://directory.google.com/Top/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Development_Tools/Code_Beautifiers/?tc=1} 

    \end{enumerate}
    \end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

As you had it, you were finishing the group before the end of the paragraph, so all the ragged settings were reverted and the paragraph was set fully justified using the default settings.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it is also possible to remove/shrink the trailing box on the link line breaking? Example: http://i.imgur.com/FPB6ou1.png

Comment: Offtopic: The spaces around those `.`s and `/`s in the URLs are really ugly; is it just the font's fault? Wonder if there's a question about this somewhere on the site…