# How to fix this url bad box for stackoverflow link?

Tags: pdftex, badness

I am really tired of them, it over and over again, they never stop coming up. Always there is some new URL which breaks and bring a new bad boxes up. How to fix this url bad box for stackoverflow link?

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
% Bad formatting using URLs in bibtex
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/bad-formatting-using-urls-in-bibtex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% How to avoid overfull error with url package?
% See also the `\usepackage{url}` declarationon the file `basic.tex`.
% Set this to 2mu or 3mu if URL start troubling again.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261776/how-to-avoid-overfull-error-with-url-package
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu

\begin{document}

    VS Code is an Editor while VS is an IDE.
    \url{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio}

\end{document}
```

Basic Builder: running pdflatex...done.

No errors. No warnings. Bad Boxes:

```
D:\temp.tex:25: Overfull \hbox (2.83554pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 25--27\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 30527522 / what -[] are -[] the -[] differences -[] between -[] visual -[] studio -[] code -[] and -[] visual -[] studio$
```

[image]

I do not want to disable the warning, I want this to not goes out of the page limits automatically. Can ever latex be able to break them to the next line without I manually go all over everything new and figure out some kinda manual hack for each case manually?

[image]

Comment: You can also write: `\url{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522}` or just `\url{stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522}` to have a shorter link.

Comment: See [How to break long url in an item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

I find URLs are a great place to employ `sloppypar`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
% Bad formatting using URLs in bibtex
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/bad-formatting-using-urls-in-bibtex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% How to avoid overfull error with url package?
% See also the `\usepackage{url}` declarationon the file `basic.tex`.
% Set this to 2mu or 3mu if URL start troubling again.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261776/how-to-avoid-overfull-error-with-url-package
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu

\begin{document}

THIS

    VS Code is an Editor while VS is an IDE.
    \url{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio}

\bigskip
VERSUS THIS
\begin{sloppypar}
    VS Code is an Editor while VS is an IDE.
    \url{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I mention in comments below, for those hating the typing associated with placing a `sloppypar` environment around every paragraph that has a `\url`, one possibility is this in the preamble:

```
\everypar{\tolerance=200\relax\emergencystretch=0pt\relax\hfuzz=0.1pt\relax\vfuzz\hfuzz}
\let\svurl\url
\renewcommand\url{\sloppy\svurl}
```

*In theory*, this would make any paragraph using `\url` into a `\sloppy` paragraph. Then, with the `\everypar`, parameters would be reset to the LaTeX defaults with each new paragraph. Of course, this would conflict with any other package that wished to redefine these parameters for other reasons.

*In practice*, this has not been tested.  And as we know, in theory, theory and practice are the same...in practice, they are not.

**METHOD 2**

Alternately, you can tell `\url` to break at any letter (ref [Manually URL linebreak with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/manually-url-linebreak-with-biblatex/102697#102697)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3.3cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
% Bad formatting using URLs in bibtex
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/bad-formatting-using-urls-in-bibtex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% How to avoid overfull error with url package?
% See also the `\usepackage{url}` declarationon the file `basic.tex`.
% Set this to 2mu or 3mu if URL start troubling again.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261776/how-to-avoid-overfull-error-with-url-package
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu

\begin{document}
THIS

    VS Code is an Editor while VS is an IDE.
    \url{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio}

\bigskip
VERSUS THIS   

    \makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{%
  \do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f%
  \do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m%
  \do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z%
  \do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G%
  \do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U%
  \do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}%
\makeatother
    VS Code is an Editor while VS is an IDE.
    \url{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I automatically put the `\begin{sloppypar}` or `\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro...` around every `\url{}`, so I can never ever had these bad box warnings?

Comment: @user The problem with that approach is that `sloppypar` begins and ends a separate paragraph, which I don't think you want for each invocation of `\url`.

Comment: @user Of course, you could use `\sloppy` in the preamble to make the whole document conform to the redefined tolerances and stretches, but many would argue that the result would look... well..., more sloppy.

Comment: Well, I just added the macro `\makeatletter \g@addto@macro...` to my preamble, and the problem is fixed. I did not had noticed the macro was redefining `\url`. I am putting this `\url` as default for all my projects. Why latex would not come with this `\url` by default?

Comment: If you wanted to automate the 1st approach, maybe this would work in the preamble: `\everypar{\tolerance=200\relax\emergencystretch=0pt\relax\hfuzz=0.1pt\relax\vfuzz\hfuzz}
\let\svurl\url
\renewcommand\url{\sloppy\svurl}`.  In theory, this would make any paragraph using `\url` into a `\sloppy` paragraph.  Then, with the `\everypar`, parameters would be reset to the LaTeX defaults with each new paragraph.  Of course, this would conflict with any other package that wished to redefine these parameters for other reasons.

Comment: As to the 2nd `\g@addto@macro` approach, which you mention above, the reason it is not the default is than many people do not wish to break `\url`s in the middle of words.

Comment: Well I would rather break them on the middle of the word, other than go out the page margins and throw these bad boxes warnings. But it did not broke my work on the middle. I hope this do not put a hyphen when breaking the words on the middle, as it would certainly confuse with the URL own hyphens.

Comment: @user I do not believe that `\url` will insert hyphens when breaking across lines.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes all love then.